# Output subtotal at each line while adding up numbers, one per line

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk, sed

For example, I have a file that looks something like this:

```
2
4
7
-3
5
-2
```

and I need the output to look like this:

```
2
6
13
10
15
13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way with awk:

```
$ awk '{print s+=$1}' file
2
6
13
10
15
13
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'NR>1{$1+=p} {p=$1} 1' file
2
6
13
10
15
13
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -nE '$x += $_; say $x' file
2
6
13
10
15
13
```